# Expo Router Issue: Navigating Between Screens Using Parentheses Grouping

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-router

Certainly, here's your initial question rephrased in English:

---

I have a folder named "app" containing an Expo router structure as follows:

```
(onboard)
  _layout.tsx
  experience.tsx
  profile.tsx
  question.tsx
(tabs)
  _layout.tsx
  about.tsx
  home.tsx
index.tsx (login)
register.tsx
```

The actual app flow is as follows:

- If the user has an account: `/login` -> `(tabs)/home`
- If the user doesn't have an account: `/register` -> `(onboard)/profile` -> `(onboard)/experience` -> `(onboard)/question` -> `(tabs)/home`

However, I'm unable to navigate to `(tabs)/home` either from `/login` or from `(onboard)/question`.

I've tried wrapping my button with:

```
<Link href="/(tabs)/about">to home from question</Link>
```

and I've also tried without `(tabs)` like:

```
<Link href="/about">to home from question</Link>
```

but it still doesn't work.

The error I'm encountering is:

```
The action 'REPLACE' with payload {"name":"about"} was not handled by any navigator.
Do you have a screen named 'about'?
```

Is there something wrong with what I'm doing?

---

And as a follow-up question, I would like to inquire about best practices when organizing the project structure. Is it considered a best practice to use grouping by adding opening and closing parentheses, such as (onboard) as I have done in my project structure? I'm wondering if this approach could potentially affect the navigation and if there's a better way to achieve the desired structure.

Also, should every grouping have an `index` file? When is it appropriate to use an index file within such a grouping?